# How to write a promotion job for multiple upstream projects in Jenkins?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have quite many build projects in jenkins (several projects with several branches each), I would like to enable them for promotion (using the promotion plugin).

The promotion process would be pretty much the same for all the different jobs. So I wouldn't like to write all the promotion steps in each of the build projects, but rather have a single promotion job, able to promote them.

The way I see it a user would manually select and promote one build from either build project. the build would trigger a new build of the promotion job, which retrieves the information from the promoted build and does the promotion.

My problem is that I don't seem to see a way to retrieve the artifacts from the promoted build.

If I use the copy artifact plugin it forces me to choose an upstream job, and I seem not to be able to write more than one. The help says that I can use the $ variables, but I don't see how, as I don't see the promoted build id among the environment variables.

I'm pretty sure this could be solved, but I don't see how.

Anyone has an idea?

thanks.

Comment: All artifacts are stored in _JENKINS_HOME/jobName/builds/number_ are you sure the jobName and number are not part of the environment variables? They should two keys of the same property

Comment: The promotion process is a build itself, and the build job I want to write is another build, they both have their own jobname and buildname. which is separate and different from the one of the promoted build. My feeling is that the promoted build data should be in the promotion process, but it's not. 

Thanks for the reply,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a promotion runs, there are two variables created during the promotion that refer back to the original job.  They are:

- PROMOTED_JOB_NAME: The name of the original job.
- PROMOTED_NUMBER: The original build number of the original job.

You can use these in actions attached to the promotion to reference the original job.  I use them with the Copy Artifacts plugin to retrieve archived files from the original build, then do things like copy to the network, publish, etc.